# Verilog bitwise or in ternary operator failing

Tags: verilog

I have a module which takes in RGB values from a MIPI camera, and outputs RGB values to a VGA port.

Here's some of the code common to every case:

```
module Overlay(
    input [10:0] x,
    input [10:0] y,

    input [7:0] red_in,
    input [7:0] green_in,
    input [7:0] blue_in,

    output [7:0] red_out,
    output [7:0] green_out,
    output [7:0] blue_out
);
```

The following code works:

```
assign {red_out, green_out, blue_out} = {red_in, green_in, blue_in};
```

Next, I wanted to make the first column white, which behaved as expected. I did it like this:

```
assign {red_out, green_out, blue_out} = (x == 0) ? 
        23'hFFFFFF : 
        {red_in, green_in, blue_in};
```

And if I try to make just the last column white, it also works:

```
parameter IMAGE_WIDTH = 640;
assign {red_out, green_out, blue_out} = (x == (IMAGE_WIDTH - 1)) ? 
        23'hFFFFFF : 
        {red_in, green_in, blue_in};
```

The problem comes when I try to do both at once. With these changes, the screen goes completely black:

```
parameter IMAGE_WIDTH = 640;
assign {red_out, green_out, blue_out} = ((x == 0) | (x == (IMAGE_WIDTH - 1)) ? 
        23'hFFFFFF : 
        {red_in, green_in, blue_in};
```

I also noticed that even with just one column, it doesn't work if I use an intermediate wire:

```
wire first_column = x == 0;
assign {red_out, green_out, blue_out} = first_column ? 
        23'hFFFFFF : 
        {red_in, green_in, blue_in};
```

I can't see the pattern in these errors. For reference, I'm building using Quartus 16.0. Also, it should be noted that I tried both the bitwise '|' and logical '||' operators in each of these cases.

Below is what the whole source file looks like:

```
module Overlay(
    input [10:0] x,
    input [10:0] y,

    input [7:0] red_in,
    input [7:0] green_in,
    input [7:0] blue_in,

    output [7:0] red_out,
    output [7:0] green_out,
    output [7:0] blue_out
);

parameter IMAGE_WIDTH = 480;
parameter IMAGE_WIDTH = 640;
assign {red_out, green_out, blue_out} = ((x == 0) | (x == (IMAGE_WIDTH - 1)) ? 
        23'hFFFFFF : 
        {red_in, green_in, blue_in};

endmodule
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code at the first glance except for a *redefinition* of the IMAGE_WIDTH. For clarity you should have used `||` in the condition. You  need to provide a **simulatable** model with a test bench which demonstrates bad results. Make sure that 'x' is initialized and does not contain `x` value. BTW, it is not a good idea to name a variable as *x* or *z*.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably secondary: But I noticed that you are assigning to 3x8=24 bit wide net (vector) but the constant you are specifying is explicitly 23 bit wide:

```
23'hFFFFFF
```

This looks like a typo and I would expect a warning. I think you wanted

```
24'hFFFFFF
```

Comment: Thanks for catching this; I wouldn't have noticed if you hadn't mentioned it